# Negative Response in IOS devices Using DATA URL

Tags: ios, html, base64, html5-audio

I have a situation here .
"I have encoded audio file to base64 format, I wanted to play the audio in iOS devices using the encoded string in the format of data URL's,... It works fine on desktop. But having problem in iOS devices.Thanks for your reading. This is how i used my encoded string with data URL

```
 data:audio/mp3;base64,SUQzA..........................=
```

Any suggestion or guideline guys.

Comment: Does the iOS browser support the method? I know chrome might but I don't know about the native browser for iOS. Try the thing in safari on desktop.

Comment: Positive response in SAFARI Desktop browser but not in Mobile Safari..

Comment: Interesting... I'd report the problem to Apple, maybe they can fix it. How does mobile chrome do?

Comment: The assumption is if chrome does it, than apple will want to do it.